# Override function seems to not be firing

Tags: swift

I have a piece of code with seemingly no errors but the override is 
     not happening and i am unable to detect device motion

```
   let motion = CMMotionManager()  

//start override
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
//check is motion is active
if motion.isDeviceMotionActive {
 //setting interval
    motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
 //starting updates
    motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: .main) {
        [weak self] (data, error) in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }

        let rotation = data.gravity.y

        self!.yAccel.text = "Accel = \(Double(rotation))"
         }
        }
       }
```

I should expect override function to consistently reload and save data to specified variable

Answer (score 0):

I could guess that you made a mistake.
There should be

```
if motion.isAccelerometerAvailable {
```

instead of:

```
if motion.isDeviceMotionActive {
```

Comment: if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable turned out to be the culprit !! thanks Serj!

Comment: Daniel, if my answer helped you, please check it as accepted